# Displaying listings of .tex sources and their .pdf outputs in a tutorial, for example

Tags: graphics

Assuming the following MWE is a tutorial in which I wish to talk about another document, SomeTexSource.tex, and wanted to (1) display its .tex source code listing, and (2) display the .pdf document produced by it, or parts thereof. The listing looks as intended, but the graphics showing the .pdf is not quite what I had hoped for. Presumably the `includegraphics` `pagebox` key values `mediabox`, `cropbox`, `bleedbox`, `trimbox`, `artbox` etc. are the key to success here, but I have given up trying making them work for me. Is there a way (a) to trim the .pdf display down from a whole page (or pages) to just those parts that have content, i.e. trim the empty patches, and (b) is there a way to selectively just show  parts of the whole document, for example Section 2.

### The Tutorial:

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 31 March 2019
%=======================
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\definecolor{macroscolor}{rgb}{0.8,0.85,1}  % light-blue
\lstset
    {
        breaklines=true
    }

%-----------------------
\begin{document}

\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\small,backgroundcolor=\color{macroscolor},commentstyle=    \color{red},
caption={SomeTexSource.tex},
label=SomeTexSource.tex]
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
If I were to discuss this short document, SomeTexSource.tex, in a tutorial and I would wish to show its listing followed by the .pdf output produced from it, how can something better be achieved than is achieved in my MWE?

\section{First Section}\label{First Section}
Wishing to demonstrate the .pdf generated by SomeTexSource.tex. The whole page is shown, inluding the page number. Is there a way to just show the bits that have content?

\section{Second Section}\label{Second Section}
Is there a way to show just Section \ref{Second Section} and not Section \ref{First Section}, for example?

    Not the world formula: $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{4n^2}{4n^2-1}=\frac{\pi}{2}$

\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}

\includegraphics[angle=0,width=1.0\linewidth]{SomeTexSource.pdf}
\end{document}
```

### The .tex source it talks about:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
If I were to discuss this short document, SomeTexSource.tex, in a tutorial and I would wish to show its listing followed by the .pdf output produced from it, how can something better be achieved than is achieved in my MWE?

\section{First Section}\label{First Section}
Wishing to demonstrate the .pdf generated by SomeTexSource.tex. The whole page is shown, inluding the page number. Is there a way to just show the bits that have content?

\section{Second Section}\label{Second Section}
Is there a way to show just Section \ref{Second Section} and not Section \ref{First Section}, for example?

    Not the world formula: $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{4n^2}{4n^2-1}=\frac{\pi}{2}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can use pdfcrop to remove the margins. But showing only parts is not so easy (at least automatically). While it is possible to retrieve and store the coordinates (with zref-savepos and zref-xr) you would then have markers in the code and so you would need a way to suppress their output in the listings.

Comment: Not sure what to make of `pdfcrop`. I installed it in Miktex but when attempting to load it with `\usepackage{pdfcrop}` I am informed `pdfcrop.sty` does not exist.

Comment: I will, once I am done playing with it, but there may be a question or two along the way.